# Gnome 3 is not allowing me to log in as root

Tags: debian, gnome

I tried to log in as root in `gnome 3` like so: I pressed `Not listed?`, then I typed in `root` as username then I typed in my root password, but it says `That didn't work`.

Comment: Many, many Linux DE (Desktop Environments) historically and intentionally denied logging in as superuser (root), because an inexperienced person could quickly ruin it.

Comment: You should **really rethink what you're doing. Having to log in as root is a sure sign you've done something wrong!

Comment: I don't have sensitive information on my pc, and if my OS will broke i will reinstall it without making a backup

Comment: This question can be useful for people that log in as root on gnome 3 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/603867/gnome-3-remember-root-log-in-credentials.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should edit the file  `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` commenting the line that contains the root user check,

```
#auth   required    pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

Answer (score -1):

While the above answer helped, only being able to log in as a user and not root, I wasn't able to edit the file mentioned above.

As long as you know the root credentials, you can switch user to root by entering the following command:

```
su
```

you'll then be prompted to enter the password, after that you should be good.