# Gnome 3 - Remember root log in credentials

Tags: debian, login, root, gnome3

When I log in as root gnome does not remember root as it does for normal users.
I can use down arrow to switch to another user, to insert root credentials.
Also it does not remember the selected sub-GUI, I am on debian 10 and unluckily the default is wayland.

I fixed that uncommenting this line from `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

If I edit the `root` file in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/`:

```
[User]
Language=
XSession=
SystemAccount=true
```

Changing `SystemAccount=false` after I reboot the system, it is reset.

Normally you cannot log in as root [Gnome 3 is not allowing me to login as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284772/gnome-3-is-not-allowing-me-to-login-as-root).

Comment: Of course you are already aware that loggin in as root is strongly discouraged.  I'll also draw you (and future readers) to the fact that [a root gnome session may not function correctly](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gdm-list/2010-March/msg00023.html).

Comment: That email is from 2010, a lot of time has passed and gnome 3 was released in 2011.

Comment: That's true, I'd picked it up from [the Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Enabling_Root_User_For_GNOME_Display_Manager) (dated September 2016).  Though closer inspection of the history shows it to be an old reference.  In any case this question deserves a health warning for future readers as a  "how to shoot myself in the foot" question.

Comment: "how to shoot myself in the foot"? https://www.garyshood.com/root/ https://xkcd.com/1200/ https://bkhome.org/archive/puppylinux/technical/root.htm

Comment: Not one of these is a security expert and the first just makes childish and rather sexist insults without offering any evidence or justification. By all means feel free to disagree with two decades of security advice and I'm not telling you "don't shoot yourself in the foot".  But questions which go against general security advice ought to come with a [health warning](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-log-in-as-root)

Comment: Obviously I totally disagree. "SECURITY!!! You'll Never Convince Me!".

Comment: Clearly I'm not trying to.